# getting error while setting up typescript lsp in neovim using lazy package manager

Tags: typescript, neovim, language-server-protocol, nvim-lspconfig, typescript-language-server

I got the below error in nvim while opening a .ts file. I have used mason, mason-lspconfig and nvim-lspconfig for setting up lsp. For lua loanguage the lsp is working properly. But for ts files, i am getting error as in the below screenshot.

[image]

Here is the screenshot of the lsp.log.

[image]

I have uploaded my config in my github, here is the link for that repo: https://github.com/MuraliPrasanth2/nvim-lazy-config

could anyone let me know, what am i need to do to resolve this issue?

When i searched for the solution, i came to know that i need to have a package.json and tsconfig file as well in the root folder, so i have used "npm init -y" to create the package.json and "tsc --init" to create a tsconfig file. But The issue is still not resolved. I am getting the same error message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I already added the github link for the config in this post

Answer (score 0):

I installed typescript-language-server from npm in the below location

```
/home/muralishal/.local/share/nvim/mason
```

using the command

```
npm install typescript-language-server
```

now the error is resolved.